# Incorrect answer from Monte Carlo integration

Tags: r, math, statistics, montecarlo, integral

How can I approximate the integral of [x^4 * sin(x)]/ [exp(1)^(x/5)] (0 to +Inf) with Monte Carlo method in R?

What I tried to do is

```
set.seed(666)
func1 <- function(x)
    {
      (x^4 * sin(x))/exp(1)^(x/5)
    }

n <- 1000000

x <- rexp(n, 0.2)
f <- func1(x)
E <- mean(f)
```

but the result of E is not right

Comment: can you give us a little more context? This looks like it might be homework. It's OK if it is, but it would be good to say if it is.  How do you know the answer isn't right? Are you comparing with an analytical solution? Are you allowed to use the fact that your expression is proportion to sin(x) times a Gamma density function ... ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195877/estimate-gamma-function-using-monte-carlo

Comment: Yes, it's homework. I'm comparing with wolfram value. I'm allowed to use the gamma density function, but have no idea how

Comment: It seems Wolfram alpha says 11.994 ... is that what you're comparing to?

Comment: Yes, my E is returning a negative number

Comment: @ 李哲源 Didn't  understand your code

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to sample from exponential, it shouldn't be used again in the function.

From code

```
set.seed(32345)

func <- function(x) { (x^4 * sin(x)) }

n <- 10000000

x <- rexp(n, 0.2)
f <- func(x)
E <- mean(f)
```

I'm getting the answer

```
[1] 13.06643
```

UPDATE

It fluctuates, and fluctuates badly.

Lest first start with the right answer which according to Mathematica is equal to
4453125/371293 = 11.9936.

I transformed integral from

I = ∫ dx exp(-x/5) x<sup>4</sup> sin(x)

using substitution `y=x/5` to

I = 5<sup>5</sup> Γ(5) ∫ dy exp(-y) y<sup>5-1</sup> / Γ(5) sin(5*y)

Everything but `sin(5*y)` is normalized gamma distribution, which we will use to sample, and `sin(5*y)` will be our function to compute mean value.

And used following trick together with large number of samples: I split calculation of positive values and negative values. It helps if you have fluctuating answer with values canceling each other. I did calculation in batches as well. Gamma function of 5 is just 4! (factorial)

Code

```
set.seed(32345)

N  <- 10000000 # number of samples per batch
NN <- 640      # number of batches

pos <- rep(0, NN) # positive values
neg <- rep(0, NN) # negative values

for(k in 1:NN) { # loop over batches
    y <- rgamma(N, shape=5, scale=1)
    f <- sin(5.0 * y)
    pnf <- ifelse(f > 0.0, f, 0.0)
    pos[k] <- mean(pnf)
    pnf <- ifelse(f < 0.0, -f, 0.0)
    neg[k] <- mean(pnf)
    print(k)
}

mean(pos)
sd(pos)/sqrt(NN)

mean(neg)
sd(neg)/sqrt(NN)

5*5*5*5*5*4*3*2*(mean(pos) - mean(neg))
```

Output

```
> mean(pos)
[1] 0.3183912
> sd(pos)/sqrt(NN)
[1] 4.749269e-06
> 
> mean(neg)
[1] 0.3182223
> sd(neg)/sqrt(NN)
[1] 5.087734e-06
> 
> 5*5*5*5*5*4*3*2*(mean(pos) - mean(neg))
[1] 12.67078
```

You could see that we really compute difference of two very close values, this is why it is hard to get convergence. It took a bit over 20 minutes to compute on my Xeon workstation.

And with different seed=12345

```
> mean(pos)
[1] 0.3183917
> sd(pos)/sqrt(NN)
[1] 4.835424e-06
> 
> mean(neg)
[1] 0.3182268
> sd(neg)/sqrt(NN)
[1] 4.633129e-06
> 
> 5*5*5*5*5*4*3*2*(mean(pos) - mean(neg))
[1] 12.36735
```

Comment: Note that these results are *extremely* unstable: `set.seed(101); summary(replicate(10,mean(func(rexp(n,0.2)))))`: c(Min. = -18.661, `1st Qu.` = -5.6832,  Median = 20.6604, Mean = 15.4167, `3rd Qu.` = 34.4519, 
Max. = 46.1750)

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, noticed that as well.

Comment: @BenBolker tried to sample from Gamma via rgamma, still fluctuates a lot, see update

Comment: I haven't looked at  李哲源 's linked answers yet, but do they help with stability? I was also thinking about rejection sampling ...

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux using your code i'm getting [1] -95.84517, why?

Comment: @Incognite Value fluctuates wildly, so while my answer has good advice - you shouldn't have exp(-x/5) counted twice - it is wrong because it didn't solve the problem. Looking into it...

Comment: @BenBolker I got something which looks better, though I'm not quite happy with the outcome

Answer (score 1):

In the following I deliberately don't set a random seed.

---

As I mentioned in my comments, there are at least two introductory Q & A on Monte Carlo integration on Stack Overflow:

- [Wrong result when doing simple Monte Carlo integration in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40971079/4891738)
- [Monte Carlo integration using importance sampling given a proposal function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40984778/4891738)

Both explained how to get Monte Carlo estimate, but forgot about the standard error of the estimate. It just turns out that Monte Carlo estimation has extremely slow convergence rate on your function.

It is commonly known that Monte Carlo integration has an `O(1 / sqrt(N))` convergence rate, where `N` is the sample size and `O()` is the **big O notation**. However, the constant behind that *big O* can be very large for some functions, so the realistic convergence rate may be much much slower.

Your functions could be defined in at least two ways:

```
## direct definition
f <- function (x) x^4 * sin(x) * exp(-x/5)

## using gamma distribution; see ?rgamma
g <- function (x) sin(x) * 5 ^ 5 * gamma(5) * dgamma(x, 5, 1/5)

curve(f, from = 0, to = 100)
curve(g, add = TRUE, col = 2)
```

[image]

The 1st Q & A explained how to compute Monte Carlo integration using uniformly distributed samples. Your function `f` or `g` is almost zero beyond `x = 200`, so integration on `[0, +Inf)` is effectively on `[0, 200]`. The following function would return you the integration and its standard error:

```
MCI1 <- function (n) {
  x <- runif(n, 0, 200)
  y <- 200 * f(x)
  c(mean.default(y), sqrt(var(y) / n))
  }
```

Another way is via importance sampling, as explained in the 2nd Q & A. Here gamma distribution is used as proposal distribution (as Ben Bolker suggested).

```
MCI2 <- function (n) {
  x <- rgamma(n, 5, 0.2)
  y <- sin(x) * 75000
  c(mean.default(y), sqrt(var(y) / n))
  }
```

Now let's check the convergence rate.

```
n <- seq(1000, by = 5000, length = 100)
tail(n)
#[1] 471000 476000 481000 486000 491000 496000

b1 <- sapply(n, MCI1)
b2 <- sapply(n, MCI2)
```

For uniform sampling, we have

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(b1[1, ], main = "estimate")
plot(b1[2, ], main = "standard error")

b1[, (ncol(b1) - 5):ncol(b1)]
#         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
#[1,] 115.1243 239.9631  55.57149 -325.8631 -140.3745  78.61126
#[2,] 181.0025 179.9988 178.99367  178.2152  177.2193 175.31446
```

[image]

For gamma sampling, we have

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(b2[1, ], main = "estimate")
plot(b2[2, ], main = "standard error")

b2[, (ncol(b2) - 5):ncol(b2)]
#           [,1]       [,2]     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
#[1,] -100.70344 -150.71536 24.40841 -49.58032 169.85385 122.81731
#[2,]   77.22445   76.85013 76.53198  76.03692  75.69819  75.25755
```

[image]

Whatever method it is, note how big the standard error is (compared with the estimate itself), and how slow it reduces.

It is much easier to use numerical integration (not surprising for integrating univariate functions):

```
integrate(f, 0, 200)
#11.99356 with absolute error < 0.0012

## trapezoidal rule
200 * mean.default(f(seq(0, 200, length = 10000)))
#[1] 11.99236
```

In the trapezoidal rule, even if only 1e+4 evenly spaced sampling points are taken, the integration is close enough to the truth.

---

**Remark**

Monte Carlo integration would have a less struggle if we do integration on a more restricted domain. From the figure of `f` or `g`, we see that this is an oscillating function. And actually, it crosses x-axis with a period of `pi`. Let's consider an integration on `[lower, upper]`.

```
MCI3 <- function (n, lower, upper) {
  x <- runif(n, lower, upper)
  y <- (upper - lower) * f(x)
  c(mean.default(y), sqrt(var(y) / n))
  }

a1 <- sapply(n, MCI3, lower = 0, upper = pi)
a2 <- sapply(n, MCI3, lower = pi, upper = 2 * pi)
a3 <- sapply(n, MCI3, lower = 2 * pi, upper = 3 * pi)
a4 <- sapply(n, MCI3, lower = 3 * pi, upper = 4 * pi)
```

```
a1[, (ncol(a1) - 5):ncol(a1)]
#            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]
#[1,] 17.04658711 16.97935808 17.01094302 17.02117843 16.96935285 16.99552898
#[2,]  0.02407643  0.02390894  0.02379678  0.02368683  0.02354298  0.02342799

a2[, (ncol(a2) - 5):ncol(a2)]
#             [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]
#[1,] -406.5646843 -404.9633321 -405.4300941 -405.4799659 -405.8337416
#[2,]    0.3476975    0.3463621    0.3442497    0.3425202    0.3409073
#             [,6]
#[1,] -405.8628741
#[2,]    0.3390045

a3[, (ncol(a3) - 5):ncol(a3)]
#            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]
#[1,] 1591.539911 1592.280780 1594.307951 1591.375340 1593.171500 1591.648529
#[2,]    1.197469    1.190251    1.183095    1.177079    1.172049    1.165667

a4[, (ncol(a4) - 5):ncol(a4)]
#             [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]
#[1,] -3235.561677 -3239.147235 -3241.532097 -3238.421556 -3238.667702
#[2,]     2.336684     2.321283     2.311647     2.300856     2.286624
#             [,6]
#[1,] -3237.043068
#[2,]     2.279032
```

Comment: @Incognite A pleasure. Your example makes me realize that Monte Carlo integration has its limitation. A much simpler is example is integrating `sin(x)` on `[0, 2 * pi]`. Clearly we know that the result is 0, but Monte Carlo integration would be very slow to converge.